# Plotting specific items of list of lists in a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, plot

I have been trying to plot the specific items of my-list in a dictionary, but the plot shows nothing. Here is the example of the dictionary and the lists:

```
mdict:{
     'week 1': [1,1,32],[1,2,43],[1,3,7],..[2,1,4],[2,2,6],[2,3,10],
     'week 2': [1,1,25],[1,2,36],[1,3,65],..[2,1,33],[2,2,45],[2,3,15],
      ...: ...
     'week n': [1,1,44],[1,2,87,[1,3,32],..[2,1,11],[2,2,5],[2,3,55]
```

}

I need to plot the the third items of the list from each key, which have the same first two elements. E.g., **"1,1,32"** and **1,1,25** and **1,1,44** from weeks 1 , 2 and should be plotted.

I have tried the following code, but it shows nothing:

```
  for key in mdict.keys():
      items, values = zip(pdict[key][0][1:3])  # Unpack
      plt.plot(items, values, label=key)
```

I am a biggener and sure I missed something to iterate

Comment: Trying to better understand what you want, do you want to check if the first and second element are equal in every list contained within each week, or just the first list in each week? Also, what do you want to then plot the third value against? (is it the first number from each list? e.g. what elements do you want items and values to reflect?)

Comment: Indeed, the first value identifies the name of the feature, the second value is the index and the third value of each list is a cumulative value which increases overtime (every week). So I want to show how they are increased (there might be some cases which they did not).  This is why I need to plot the similar features from the weeks. So X axis should be week1, week2,... and Y axis is the value of that week (which is the third value of the items in the list). If they are in order, yes, we can consider the first list of each week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your response I did up a quick answer (I'm sure some people could improve on it). Hopefully this is what you're looking for if not maybe you can edit it as you see fit.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import cm
import numpy as np


mdict = {
     'week 1': [[1,1,32],[1,2,43],[1,3,7],[2,1,4],[2,2,6],[2,3,10]],
     'week 2': [[1,1,25],[1,2,36],[1,3,65],[2,1,33],[2,2,45],[2,3,15]]
        }

color=iter(cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0,1,len(mdict.keys()))))

for key in mdict.keys():
    c=next(color) #Change colour for each weeks data
    #Initialise empty lists for each week
    items = []
    values = []
    
    for l in mdict[key]: #Loop through lists within each week
        
        if l[0] == l[1]: #If first two elements match, append necessary elements
            items.append(l[0])
            values.append(l[2])
            
    plt.plot(items, values, 'o', c=c, label=key) #Plot all data for each week
    
plt.legend(loc="upper left")
```